# Using display: table-cell to create two column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use display:table-cell to create a two column layout where the two columns will be the same height, that height being dictated by the content of the largest column. However, the div with the content with less in doesn't stretch to the same height as the other and I can't work out why.

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="ttl">
        <p>Column 1 Content Column 1 Content.......</p>
    <div class="otr">
        <p>Column 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css as below:

```
.col {
    width:966px;
    display:table;
}
.ttl {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:20px;
    width: 571px;
    background: #FFF;
    display: table-cell;
}
.otr {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 255px;
    background: #FFF;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/8rjua9w7/). However, you forgot to close your first child `</div>`.

Comment: @Vucko [No it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/8rjua9w7/1/), not when there's longer content in one than the other.

Comment: @MilindR remove the `float` property from the child `divs` and it will work.

Comment: @Vucko oops you did say it first... what shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the `float: left`. [Removing it](http://jsfiddle.net/8rjua9w7/2/) solves the problem.

```
html,body{width:100%;margin:0}

.col {
    width:966px;
    display:table;
}
.ttl { width: 571px; background: red; }
.otr { width: 255px; background: blue;}

.ttl, .otr {
   margin-left:20px;
   padding:20px;
   display: table-cell;
}
```

I also deduplicated your CSS code while at it.